# Realm Swift: Realm Build Errors After Linking

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

I've created a new project `MyApp`, added a `Podfile` as follows:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘Coffee’ do
  pod 'QuadratTouch', '>= 1.0'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

Then, I closed the project, run `pod install` from the command line and everything was installed correctly. I then opened the workspace and built the project `(cmd+b)` and was hit with ***44 errors*** originating from Realm.
[image]
Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Xcode: v 7.2.1
iOS: 9.0
Mac: OSX El Capitan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Realm (1.0.1) requires Swift 2.2 which is a part of Xcode 7.3. So you should update Xcode to the latest version.

Realm Swift 0.102.1 was the last version to support Xcode 7.2.1.